# Item in RecyclerView not filling it's width match_parent

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a problem with my `RecyclerView` and its child items. They do not extend through the whole `android:layout_width="match_parent"` nor `fill_parent`. I've tried both. The thing is, this work perfectly and with no changes, it got ruined somehow.

I am showing this in a `FragmentDialog` and the child items only expand like `wrap_content` when I scroll the view up and down, they are fully expanded but as soon as I click on them (I call `notifyDataSetChanged()`) they shrink again.

Here is a picture of a properly filled item and below it's how they are when they load or when I notifyData. Also the `StickHeaderAdapter` that I use, does not show headers until I click on one of the items (this work previously and I changed nothing on that part either).

[image: recyclerview child problem]

Here is the code for the child row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<carbon.widget.LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:carbon_rippleColor="@color/green"
    app:carbon_rippleStyle="background">

<carbon.widget.TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/block_name"
    android:padding="@dimen/block_row_padding"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textSize="@dimen/block_row_text_size"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    app:carbon_rippleColor="@color/green"
    app:carbon_rippleStyle="background"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/download_layout"
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:visibility="gone">


    <carbon.widget.ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/downloading_bar"
        app:carbon_progressStyle="circular_indeterminate"
        app:carbon_barWidth="5dp"
        app:carbon_tint="@color/green"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <carbon.widget.TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/block_progress_download"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the part of the adapter code where I create `ViewHolder`:

```
@Override
public BlockAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.block_row, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}
```

This is the binding code if it helps:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(BlockAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (blockData.isDownloading()) {
        holder.download_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.download_bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (blockData.getProgress() != null) {
            holder.download_progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.download_progress.setText(String.format("%d%%", blockData.getProgress()));
        }
    } else {
        holder.download_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.download_bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.download_progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if (selected) {
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
        holder.block_name.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    } else {
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        holder.block_name.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
    }

}
```

I don't know why this work in the morning and changed later...

**Things I tried:**

- Change `match_parent` for `fill_parent`
- Set `RecyclerView.LayoutParams` to `LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT`
- Change width programatically
- Change createViewHolder from `..., parent, false);` to `..., null);` and add Params seperatelly
- Logged the width (sometimes it's like 390, when I scroll it gets to 990 and when I click back to 390)
- Setup `StickHeaders` sooner, but they are all set when they get created and header is there, it's just invisible.

ANY HELP IS APPRECIATED!

Comment: Did you try using a *normal* `LinearLayout`? I have no idea what `carbon.widget.LinearLayout` is or what it does

Comment: It simply adds ripple effect for clicking items. It worked with that before :/

Comment: Well it does some custom measuring, so I would not fully trust that. You should try if it works with a normal layout.

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work with normal either

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The problem is within the new support library `23.2.0`, so I reverted that to `23.1.1` and it works fine. If I find a solution, or what to change, I will let you know, otherwise I'm leaving this thread open, if someone else finds a better answer.

**UPDATE**

Ok, so I decided it was time to fix this, as we need to move to new support libraries and I finally found an answer.

The problem was/is that the new `LayoutManager` is using `autoMeasure()` and somehow it changed all my `match_parent` to `wrap_content`, so here is what you need to do, if you encounter a similar problem.

First create `LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());`

then `llm.setAutoMeasureEnabled(false);`

and finally you set the `LinearLayoutManager` to your `RecyclerView`, but do this **AFTER** `recyclerView.setAdapter(yourAdapter);`

Here is a quick example:

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
llm.setAutoMeasureEnabled(false);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
```

Comment: I find it a little ridiculous that these `.setLayoutManager()` and `.setAdapter()` ordering bugs exist

Comment: This worked for me thanks. Im using RecyclerView 25.2.0 and I set the layout manager first, then setAutoMeasureEnabled(false) and then the adapter which worked

Comment: Works, and I set `setAutoMeasureEnabled` before `setAdapter ` also work. My `RecyclerView` version is v26.1.0

Comment: Since API v27.1.0 we need to extend the LinearLayoutManager and override the isAutoMeasureEnabled() function to return false because setAutoMeasureEnabled() method is removed.

Comment: @anqe1ki11er I tried it too. Its not working. So, ended up implementing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49468092/4632372) solution.

Answer (score 22):

To walkaround this bug I changed:

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
```

with:

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your Recycle view dependency to the latest.. able to get rid of that doing soo..   - i updated to 1.3.0

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem was MATCH_PARENT was not working properly.
So what did the trick for me is, just setting item width to its parent's width while inflating the view:

```
val binding = ItemNewsVerticalBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false)
binding.root.layoutParams.width = parent.width
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It happens only to some view, and it is reproducible.

Overriding setAutoMeasureEnabled to return false didn't work, for whatever reason.

I use androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0

I worked around this issue by resetting the view's width to match the parent's width, i.e.,

```
this.itemView.getLayoutParams().width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
this.itemView.requestLayout();
```

at the end of binding the ViewHolder. `this.itemView` is the ViewHolder's root view in this case, i.e. `androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder.itemView`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem as well. I was able to fix it simply by avoiding use of "MATCH_PARENT" for width, and instead setting the layout_constraintStart_toStartOf and layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf to "0", and setting the width to match constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the answers, nothing works for me.

After lot of research find the another way to fix this issue.

Create a custom layout manager and set this custom layout manager into your recyclerview.

**Step 1: Create custom layout manager**

```
import android.content.Context
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class FullWidthLinearLayoutManager : LinearLayoutManager {
    constructor(context: Context?) : super(context) {}
    constructor(context: Context?, orientation: Int, reverseLayout: Boolean) : super(
        context,
        orientation,
        reverseLayout
    ) {
    }

    override fun checkLayoutParams(lp: RecyclerView.LayoutParams): Boolean {
        lp.width = width
        return true
    }
}
```

**Step 2: Set this layout manager**

```
val layoutManager = FullWidthLinearLayoutManager(context)
layoutManager.orientation = LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL
yourRecyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
```